# AFURLSessionManager parse issue

Tags: xcode, parsing, afnetworking

I'm trying to run my project using afnetworking. It was working at the university, but at home I'm getting 20 errors.

```
MiniProjet Group
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/MapViewController.m
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/MapViewController.m:17:17: Method definition for 'restZoom:' not found
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/DetailController.m
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/DetailController.m:39:30: Assigning to 'id<UITableViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'DetailController *const __strong'
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h:207:52: Expected a type
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h:220:52: Expected a type
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h:231:60: Expected a type
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h:247:56: Expected a type
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h:260:59: Expected a type
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/RestaurantsView.m
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/RestaurantsView.m:32:35: Assigning to 'id<UITableViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'RestaurantsView *const __strong'
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:90:31: Unknown type name 'NSProgress'
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:90:1: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:91:31: Unknown type name 'NSProgress'
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:91:1: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:121:29: Use of undeclared identifier 'NSProgress'
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:122:31: Use of undeclared identifier 'NSProgress'
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:142:24: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:143:24: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:218:26: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:248:26: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:249:26: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:256:26: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:257:26: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union
/Users/ahmed/Desktop/Archive copie 2/MiniProjet/MiniProjet/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m:443:52: Expected a type
Warning: CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS specified without a valid Developer Signing Identity for iOS.
Too many errors emitted, stopping now
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with AFNetworking.  Why is `MapViewController.m` in your AFNetworking folder?

It seems way more likely that you have mismatched brackets or a missing semicolon in `MapViewController.m`.